# Are SATA,USB, Ethernet, mouse, keyboard, serial/parallel ports connected to Southbridge via PCI bus?

Tags: bus

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motherboard#Integrated_peripherals):

[image: Wikipedia screengrab]

I was wondering how to understand the right-down corner of the picture?

Are SATA,USB, Ethernet, mouse, keyboard, and serial/parallel ports connected to Southbridge via PCI bus?
In other words, are the buses from Southbridge and Super I/O to "Cables and ports leading-off board" PCI buses?

Comment: The used picture is outdated. Today Intel as well as AMD system don't have a Northbridge anymore. It is integrate into the CPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Are SATA,USB, Ethernet, mouse, keyboard, and serial/parallel ports connected to Southbridge via PCI bus? I**

No those items are only connected to the southbridge and super-io chips

> **are the buses from Southbridge and Super I/O to "Cables and ports leading-off board" PCI buses?**

The lines to "cables and ports ..." are the respective rs232, USB etc types of electrical connection, not PCI

Comment: Thanks! Are USB ports really directly connected to southbridge without PCI bus in between, as shown in the picture? Why in the output of `udevadm info -a -n /dev/sdb` for an external USB 2.0 HDD connected to a laptop, there is an item for PCI (see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45791/understand-output-of-udevadm-info-a-n-dev-sdb))?

Comment: @Tim, For example, see block diagram on P12 of [manual](http://developer.amd.com/assets/45215_sb710_ds_pub_1.25.pdf) for AMD SB710. Details depend on chipset used on motherboard. Note "A-Link Express and A-Link Express II are essentially PCIe 1.1 x4 lanes." according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_AMD_chipsets#A-Link_Express_II) but this isn't the bus used for PCI slots.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure what I should look at in the diagram. (1) Is "PCI bridge" the southbridge? (2) Do you mean for some, USB ports are directly connected to southbridge without a PCI, and for others, there is a PCI bus in between?

Comment: @Tim: the whole thing is the southbridge chip. The PCI-bridge is a small area of circuitry on the southbridge chip. There is no single masterplan for computers, each chipset and motherboard has it's own way of doing things.

Comment: USB host controllers are PCI(-E) devices, even if they are integrated into the "southbridge". (In quotes because that name is becoming obsolete, but there's still a functional equivalent.) The "Super I/O chip" shown above is attached to the "LPC", Low Pin Count, bus. This is a seven-wire (minimum) serial bus that logically emulates the old ISA bus. LPC in turn is supported by a PCI to LPC bridge, was is also inside the "southbridge".